# Php Unit getMockBuilder vs Mockery

Tags: phpunit, laravel-8, mockery

Working a Laravel project that uses `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` class to run unit tests.  In order to create mocks it sometimes uses the built in [PHPUnit Api](https://docs.phpunit.de/en/10.1/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html). e.g.

```
$this->mock = $this->getMockBuilder(ClassToMockName::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->onlyMethods(["this", "that", "theOtherMethodName"])
            ->getMock();
```

Other times it uses the [Mockery](https://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/) library, e.g.

```
$this->mock = \Mockery::mock(ClassToMock::class)->makePartial();
```

Are these to methods simply two different ways of making mocks?  What are the pros and cons of each?

Could not find much on this topic except for articles like [Tips to use for Mockery](https://darkghosthunter.medium.com/php-10-tips-to-use-for-mockery-33673ba01321) which don't explain what makes one is preferred over the other.

Answer (score 1):

It may be using Mockery so that static method calls within the method you're testing can be stubbed. PHPUnit does not support this.